# Binding single property to parent items source

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show a list of questions in a ListBox. Each ListBoxItem contains the question and a ListBox with RadioButtons that show the answer options. The ItemsSource of the first ListBox is an observerable collection with objects of class Question. The ItemsSource of the second ListBox is a list property in QuestionClass: QuestionObj.Answers.
My problem is to bind RadioButton property GroupName to the Question property QuestionObj.Index. How can I solve this?

Here is the code of class Question:

```
public class Question
{
    private static int countQuestions;

    private int index;
    private string questionText;
    private List<String> answers = new List<String>();

    public Question()
    {
        countQuestions++;
    }
    public Question(string type, bool isRequired, string questionText, List<String> answers = null) :this()    
    {
        this.index = countQuestions;
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return index; }
    }
    public string QuestionText
    {
        get { return questionText; }
    }
    public List<String> Answers
    {
        get { return answers; }
    }
}
```

and here the xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Questions" ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionList}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding QuestionText}"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="AnswerOptions" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" GroupName={Binding ??????}/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Changed SelectedIndex to SelectedItem.Index

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding}" 
             GroupName={Binding ElementName=Questions, Path=SelectedItem.Index}/>
```

Have a look here. [www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

Comment: Your solution is not working here, because all radiobuttons get the value of SelectedIndex. I need a unique index for each qustion.